# Recreated Snake in Rust

Tags: game, rust, snake-game

This is my first ever program in Rust. I've made it using only the book, the reference, and any documentation about the crates/functions I was using on the official rust lang website.

I have the feeling this could be cleaned up a lot. I'm looking for suggestions.

```
extern crate rand;
extern crate device_query;

use std::{vec, thread::sleep, time::Duration};
use rand::*;
use device_query::{DeviceQuery, DeviceState, Keycode};

fn main(){
    let device_state = DeviceState::new();
    let mut rows = [['⬛'; 11]; 11];
    let mut score: i32 = 0;
    let mut direction: u8 = 0; // = Up, 1 = Left, 2 = Down, 3= Right
    let mut positions:Vec<(usize, usize)>  = vec![(5,5)]; //every square taken by our slithery friend
    let mut close_game: bool = false;
    rows[5][5] = '';
    rows[3][5] = '';
    while !close_game {
        print!("\x1B[2J\x1B[1;1H");
        direction = input_direction(direction, &device_state);
        close_game = game_tick(&mut rows, &mut positions, direction, &mut score);
        draw_game(&rows, &score);
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(300));
    }
    println!("Game over! Final Score: {}", score);
} 

fn draw_game(a: &[[char;11];11], score: &i32){
    println!("");
    println!("  Score:{:02} teo.snake", &score);
    for i in 1..10 {
        print!("  ");
        for j in 1..10 {
            print!("{}", a[i][j]);
        }
        println!("");
    }
}

fn game_tick(a: &mut[[char;11];11], vec: &mut Vec<(usize, usize)>, d: u8, s: &mut i32)-> bool {
    let mut game_over: bool = false;
    let newpos: (usize, usize)= newposition(d, vec[0], &mut game_over);
    if game_over == true {
        return game_over
    }

    for i in 0..vec.len() {
        if newpos == vec[i] {
            game_over = true;
            return game_over
        }
    }
    vec.insert(0, newpos);

    let mut next_fruitx:usize;
    let mut next_fruity:usize;
    let mut checkpass: bool;

    'looptillvalid: loop {
        checkpass = true;
        next_fruitx = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..10);
        next_fruity = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..10);
        for i in 0..vec.len() {
            if (next_fruitx, next_fruity) == vec[i] {
                checkpass = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if checkpass == true {    
            break 'looptillvalid;
        }
    }
    let lastpos: (usize, usize) = vec.pop().unwrap();
    a[lastpos.0][lastpos.1] = '⬛';

    match a[newpos.0][newpos.1] {
        '' => { vec.push(lastpos);
            a[newpos.0][newpos.1] = ''; 
            a[lastpos.0][lastpos.1] = '';
            *s += 1; 
            game_over = false;
            a[next_fruitx][next_fruity] = '';
        }
         _  => { a[newpos.0][newpos.1] = '';
            game_over = false}
    }

    game_over
}

fn newposition(d: u8, first: (usize, usize), go: &mut bool) -> (usize, usize){
    let mut ret: (usize, usize) = (0,0);
    match d {
        0 => { ret.0 = first.0 - 1; ret.1 = first.1}
        1 => { ret.0 = first.0; ret.1 = first.1 - 1}
        2 => { ret.0 = first.0 + 1; ret.1 = first.1}
        3 => { ret.0 = first.0; ret.1 = first.1 + 1}
        _ => {println!("Invalid Direction")}
    }

    if ret.0 < 1 || ret.0 > 9 || ret.1 < 1 || ret.1 > 9 {
        *go = true;
    }

    ret
}

fn input_direction(d: u8, d_state: &DeviceState) -> u8{

    let mut dir: u8 = d;
    
    let keys: Vec<Keycode> = d_state.get_keys(); 
        if keys.len() != 0 {
            match keys[0] {
                
                Keycode::Up => {dir = 0}
                Keycode::Left => {dir = 1}
                Keycode::Down => {dir = 2}
                Keycode::Right => {dir = 3}
                _ => ()
            }
        }
    dir
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Clippy

One of the most important tools when writing good rust code is [clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy). I recommend to configure your editor to run clippy on-the fly. It has very nice messages and includes an explanation for most lints. Let's go through some of it's suggestions:

```
warning: empty string literal in `println!`
  --> src/main.rs:31:5
   |
31 |     println!("");
   |     ^^^^^^^^^--^
   |              |
   |              help: remove the empty string
   |
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#println_empty_string
   = note: `#[warn(clippy::println_empty_string)]` on by default
```

```
warning: equality checks against true are unnecessary
  --> src/main.rs:45:8
   |
45 |     if game_over == true {
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: try simplifying it as shown: `game_over`
   |
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#bool_comparison
   = note: `#[warn(clippy::bool_comparison)]` on by default
```

This one actually applies to all popular languages. Let's see one more:

```
warning: length comparison to zero
   --> src/main.rs:115:8
    |
115 |     if keys.len() != 0 {
    |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: using `!is_empty` is clearer and more explicit: `!keys.is_empty()`
    |
    = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#len_zero
    = note: `#[warn(clippy::len_zero)]` on by default
```

Then, it has many issues related to iteration. In rust, it is unidiomatic to use explicit indexing when you can iterate over the actual values instead:

```
    for row in a {
        print!("  ");
        for elem in row {
            print!("{}", elem);
        }
        println!();
    }
```

```
    for pos in &*vec {
        if newpos == *pos {
            game_over = true;
            return game_over
        }
    }
```

Here, the assignment to `game_over` is actually useless, because you can just return true directly.

## Use Rust 2021

The 2021 is the latest edition is the newest and should be used for all new code. If you're following a book or tutorial and it tells you to `extern crate`, it's very outdated.

## Control flow logic

It may just be me, but I find the control flow of the loop in gametick very confusing. I think it is more readable if written this way:

```
    loop {
        next_fruitx = thread_rng().gen_range(1..10);
        next_fruity = thread_rng().gen_range(1..10);
        if vec.contains(&(next_fruitx, next_fruity)) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

`vec.contains` can also be used in other places. Finding these is an exercise to the reader.

At the end of game_tick, both branches of the match (which reads very nicely btw) contain the line `game_over = false`. They can be removed and replaced with a single `false` at the end of the function.

## Constants

There are multiple occurrences of various constants in the code. This is both not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and also an instance of a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). Things I would extract into named constants are 11, 9, and the emojis. This reduces the risk of typos that can become logic errors.

## Data Structures

You use a lot of Tuples for Coordinates, where I think a simple Struct with `x` and `y` fields could be more readable.

Since `direction` only has 4 valid values, I would make an enum for it. That way, you can remove the "Invalid direction" error, which should be unreachable.

I'd also write a 2-valued enum for the return type of `game_tick`, as the meaning of true and false aren't very obvious.

Thanks for reading all of this. Feel free to make a new post with updated code.

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you so much